# Does it mean we can never know the exact area of circle?

Tags: circles, pi

I performed three calculations for a circle of radius $10^7$ metre

$$(\pi-3.14)(10^7)^{2}=1.59265359\times10^{11}$$

$$(\pi-3.1415926535897)(10^{7})^2=9.31$$

$$(\pi-3.141592653589793238462)(10^{7})^2=0.00000006433832795028842$$
It implies large difference in the calculated area of the circle and it's dependence on the accuracy of value of $\pi$ used.

Since we may never know the actual value of $\pi$,Does it imply that it is impossible to calculate the exact value of the area of a circle?

Comment: We actually know the exact value of pi. It is not just rational. It just cannot be expressed in finite decimal.

Comment: @jnyan. We know a "few" decimal of $\pi$ ! This makes its beauty. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$S=\pi R^2$
assume $R$ is a constant.

take ligarithmic derivative,

$\frac{\delta S}{S}=\frac{\delta\pi}{\pi}$

$\delta S=\delta \pi.R^2$

so if $R$ is large, the error on the surface is also large.